# Убрать переносы строк в mdb базе без access

Tags: access, mdb

Имеется бд в старом mdb формате. В ней есть невидимые переносы строк [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

которые в любом табличном редакторе становятся новой строкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно удалить подобные переносы в таблице? Средства MS Office Access отсутствуют. UPDATE table1 SET attr1 = trim(attr1) в MDBPlus толку не даёт.

UPDATE table1 SET attr1 = replace([attr1 ], chr(10), " ") говорит что неопределённая функция replace. По гуглу - в старых версиях mdb не было этой функции.

Пример базы https://dropmefiles.com/b0zTs

Comment: *Средства MS Office Access отсутствуют.* А что есть-то? Офис какой-нить - из него несложно выполнить программно изменение (через DAO) или импорт с нужным преобразованием. *в любом табличном редакторе становятся новой строкой* Да ладно... выложите куда-нить файл, посмотрим.

Comment: @Akina добавил пример базы.

Comment: Теперь укажите проблемную таблицу и проблемное поле. Если судить по имени поля и дате модификации таблицы в базе - это таблица `КлассОбъектов1`? Но в ней в поле `Атрибут1` нет никаких переносов строк...

Comment: @Akina попробуйте перенести таблицу в open или libre office. При вставке сразу будут видны переносы https://imgur.com/rVg9JS8

Comment: @Akina пробую в MDB Plus Viewer экспорт как csv и получаю это https://imgur.com/KY9Ghex

Comment: Что в Access, что в Excel - не нахожу проблемы. [Импорт в Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaLiS.png). [Запрос в Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHNXY.png). Ну есть там в начале значения LineFeed... а то, что вьювер сносится на новую строку - так это его бага имхо. Ну попробуй `UPDATE [КлассОбъектов1] SET [Атрибут1] = Mid([Атрибут1], 2) WHERE Asc([Атрибут1]) = 10;`... Или возьми более вменяемый инструмент для работы с БД.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101007/discussion-between--and-akina).